# After .NET 7 using aot release , windoss COM can't use correctly

Tags: .net, aot

After .net 7 is released using AOT, the shortcut created by WshShell cannot be used normally

can you give me some advice?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.